# How to Make Permutation From 7 Character Show 4 Character?

Tags: javascript, permutation

I want to make permutation with javascript, this is my code

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

for (let i1 = 0; i1 < arr.length; i1++) {
  for (let i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < arr.length; i2++) {
    for (let i3 = i2 + 1; i3 < arr.length; i3++) {
      for (let i4 = i3 + 1; i4 < arr.length; i4++) {
         console.log(arr[i1] + ' ' + arr[i2] + ' ' + arr[i3] + ' ' + arr[i4]);
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/esw6c483/1/

result from that code:

`["1 2 3 4", "1 2 3 5", "1 2 3 6", "1 2 3 7", "1 2 4 3", "1 2 4 5", "1 2 4 6", ...............]`

I want to ask, why are all the results from the permutation not displayed? From these results I did not see the numbers

`["7 1 2 3", "7 1 2 4", "7 1 2 5" ..... etc]`

please tell Me where the error from this code? or if You have a better code please help Me.

*please don't use `continue` if there are similarities in number because that only removes the number but makes the permutation process take a long time. and in my opinion it doesn't help me

Thank you

Comment: You're starting from each `i + 1` in inner loops. If you want to include those numbers, start from `0` for each inner loop (you may need to perform checks to avoid duplicates).

Comment: yes the answer from the link you provided is what I was looking for. but there is no code that gives examples of how to display 4 characters from 7 characters

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in the internal loops, you omit the first element (by starting at `iN + 1`); which is good on the first iteration, but will omit the wrong element after that.

So, you could check the outer indices instead.

Using `continue` statements for this isn't *necessary*, but it neither slows down the loop, nor omit possible cases, if used correctly. Slowing down occur because the working version iterates over more variations, not because of `continue`.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

for (let i1 = 0; i1 < arr.length; i1++) {
  for (let i2 = 0; i2 < arr.length; i2++) {
    if(i1 === i2) continue
    for (let i3 = 0; i3 < arr.length; i3++) {
      if([i1, i2].includes(i3)) continue
      for (let i4 = 0; i4 < arr.length; i4++) {
        if([i1, i2, i3].includes(i4)) continue
        console.log(arr[i1] + ' ' + arr[i2] + ' ' + arr[i3] + ' ' + arr[i4]);
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a recursive function (I highly recommened that), that eliminates code duplication and makes it more flexible.

Here's the code [I've posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62437074/8376184) to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62436810/8376184), but applies to this as well:

```js
const variations = (arr, n = arr.length) => {
  if(n === 0) return [[]]
  if(!(n >= 0)) return []
  const output = []
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr.indexOf(arr[i]) < i) continue
    const newArr = arr.slice()
    newArr.splice(i, 1)
    output.push(...variations(newArr, n - 1).map(e => [arr[i], ...e]))
  }
  return output
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(variations(arr, 4))

//If you want to concatenate them, use:

console.log(variations(arr, 4).map(e => e.join(' ')))
```

```css
/* Just to make console fill the available space */
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: @ggorlen Actually, I use it to ***find the duplicates***... So, if you call `variations([1, 1, 2], 2)`, it won't output `[1, 1]`, `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` twice, but still allows the duplicate elements to occupy different places (like `[1, 1]`), opposed to converting the input to `Set`. Checking for already used elements isn't necessary, as the recursive calls don't even receive them (they're `splice`d out)

Answer (score 0):

you can make these changes to your algorithm then it works fine

```
for (let i1 = 0; i1 < arr.length; i1++) {
  for (let i2 = 0; i2 < arr.length; i2++) {
    if (i2 != i1) {
      for (let i3 = 0; i3 < arr.length; i3++) {
        if(i2 != i3 &&  i3 != i1){
          for (let i4 = 0; i4 < arr.length; i4++) {
            if(i4 != i3 &&  i4 != i1 && i4!= i2){
              console.log(arr[i1] + ' ' + arr[i2] + ' ' + arr[i3] + ' ' + arr[i4])
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```